# android sdk product flavors - activity not found when I start a new activity using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have a working app to which I have added 2 product flavors.  This app has a menu on the first screen which allows the user to choose the next activity, which I load with an intent.

Here is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.aloedu.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.aloedu.guideddrawing.GuidedLetterDrawingActivity"
        android:label="Guided Letter Drawing"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.aloedu.buildvocabulary.BuildVocabularyActivity"
        android:label="Image Plus Word"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.aloedu.findthepicture.FindThePictureActivity"
        android:label="Find the Picture"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.aloedu.findtheletter.FindTheLetterActivity"
        android:label="Find the Letter"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.aloedu.fillintheletter.FillInTheLetterActivity"
        android:label="Find the Letter"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.aloedu.EndActivity"
        android:label="End Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.aloedu.AdminActivity"
        android:label="Admin Activity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        />

</application>

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Here is the relevant portion of the gradle file:

```
productFlavors {
    de {
        applicationIdSuffix ".de"
        versionName "1.1de"
    }
    fr {
        applicationIdSuffix ".fr"
        versionName "1.1fr"
    }
}
```

Here is the source tree:

[image]

Here is the code where I load the next activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.alpha.aloedu", newClassName);
    currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
    currentActivity.finish();
```

I have set a breakpoint on the second line and "newClassName" has the correct value.  However, when I run the "deDebug" variant,  I get an error on the third line:

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
 Unable to find explicit activity class 
{com.alpha.aloedu/com.alpha.aloedu.guideddrawing.GuidedLetterDrawingActivity};
 have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

The class GuidedLetterDrawingActivity does exist in the main source tree, and also in AndroidManifest.xml.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you added your activity in Manifeast file ?

Comment: yes, it is in the manifest file under "main"

Comment: did you check if the Activity name defined in the manifest is proper, means you have given the proper path?

Comment: yes -- without the flavors, the app works perfectly, so the manifest file must be correct -- I didn't change it when I added the flavors

Answer (score 0):

You must declare activities of each flavor in its manifest file
...\src\ **de** \AndroidManifest.xml
...\src\ **fr** \AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Declare each new activity in manifest. Even if you change the name you have to modify the manifest file.

```
     <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".new_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".new_Activity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    </application>
```

This has to be declared in main java file

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
```

execute the intent block of code as per your requirement in the same or different functions.

Comment: I have edited my original question to include the manifest file.